# How to style image inside multiple classes

Tags: css

I have the following structure of classes.

```
<div class="row newsfeed"> 
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"> 
        <div class="card"> 
            <div class="wrapper_newsfeed"> 
                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="../resources/img/og_logo.jpg" alt="image">
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I want to style the image using `.newsfeed` and `.card`. This is what I tried:

```
.newsfeed .card > .card-img-top {
    border-radius: 0;
    filter: brightness(100%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
.newsfeed .card:hover > .card-img-top {
    filter: brightness(120%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

But it's not working. I tried different ways but they didn't work either and I think this one is the closest. What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `.card-imt-top` is not a direct child of `.card`!

You shouldn't be using the direct child selector `>`.

Here is a working snippet where I added an image:

```css
.newsfeed .card{ /* Added to see the div */
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.newsfeed .card .card-img-top {
    border-radius: 0;
    filter: brightness(100%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
.newsfeed .card:hover .card-img-top {
    filter: brightness(120%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row newsfeed">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper_newsfeed">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRWRHRpOLWW0U-Sxw8Kcdkf_AFvbL1-9pNmBxWIUGfPSprrY2o6" alt="image" width="100" height="100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: exactly . thought of it

Comment: @nived It seems so! Maybe you needed a break. :)

Answer (score 1):

`.card-img-top` isn't direct child of `.card` because you have `.wrapper_newsfeed` between, so you can't use `>` selector.

```
.newsfeed .card .card-img-top {
  border-radius: 0;
  filter: brightness(100%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
.newsfeed .card:hover .card-img-top {
  filter: brightness(120%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.newsfeed .card .card-img-top {
    border-radius: 0;
    filter: brightness(100%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}

.newsfeed .card:hover .card-img-top {
filter: brightness(120%);
-webkit-filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

I think this works. `>` is direct child selector, which is wrong in this case.